# Prev Next with jquery

Tags: jquery, button

I need to go through elements with previuous and next buttons but am having trouble working out how to do it. Can you help. The prev/next should also loop continuously ie. when you get to the last item it goes to the first and when you get to the first item through prev the next click will take you to the last item and so forth.

```
<ul>
<li>Number 1 item</li>
<li>Number 2 item</li>
<li>Number 3 item</li>
<li>Number 4 item</li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks,
C

Comment: What do you mean "go through elements"? Your question lacks **context**.

Comment: what do you mean by go through elements?

Comment: Okay. What I am trying to do is much more than this but say I want to colour all elements green and using the prev next buttons it highlights the li tag red.

Comment: Do you want to go one by on highliting them?

Comment: Yes. That's right. It's for a bigger project and I'm trying to piece differnet bits of functionality together of which this is one piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rtmdj/)

Html:

```
<ul>
  <li>Number 1 item</li>
  <li>Number 2 item</li>
  <li>Number 3 item</li>
  <li>Number 4 item</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" class="next" value=">" />
<input type="button" class="prev" value="<" />
```

Javascript:

```
(function(){
    var $lis = $('ul li');
    var index = 0, lastIndex = 0;

    start(); // activate first, add event listeners to buttons

    function next(){
        lastIndex = index;
        if(++index == $lis.length) index = 0; // if next is out of bounds go to first
        $lis.eq(index).addClass('active');
        $lis.eq(lastIndex).removeClass('active');
    };

    function prev(){
        lastIndex = index;
        if(--index < 0) index = ($lis.length - 1); // if prev is less than first to to last
        $lis.eq(index).addClass('active');
        $lis.eq(lastIndex).removeClass('active');
    };
    function start(){
        $lis.eq(0).addClass('active');
        $('.next').click(next);
        $('.prev').click(prev);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example that you can use - [posted on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/H2hjr/)

Comment: My continuation on this will be to load images via ajax. The thing is I don't beleive jquery can use the load() function to load images. Thanks for all the help!!!

Comment: if your ajax request sends back a path to the image you want to load you can use plain javascript, make a new Image() and set the src property to the path of the image you want to load. You can then use jquery to listen for when the image has loaded : myImage.load(function()...